# How to get the new minecraft launcher GUI

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

My friend told me that he was running a new Minecraft launcher that looked prettier. It looks like this:

[image: Launcher]

So for him it automatically installed and recently I've been getting a bunch of updates for my launcher but not the GUI.

I've looked online and I cant find anyone with a similar problem. My PC details:

- Windows 7
- Launcher Version 1.6.76

I've tried:

- Checking the Minecraft launcher properties and the official Minecraft forum [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_launcher)
- I noticed that there was a development version 2.0.673-stage and i thought this must be it but there was no instructions on how to get it.

My launcher currently looks like this:

[image: Current Launcher]

Really my question is how do I get this new shiny GUI, and is it recommended that I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the launcher is slowly being rolled out/activated. If your launcher recently downloaded a ~40MB update, then you will get the new launcher GUI within today and next Friday, unless your Operating System is unsupported(AKA anything older than Windows 7).

Comment: Thank's I'll tick this question if it is correct. I was looking at a tutorial and I redownloaded the launcher to get the new directories and so I don't have to use java in Minecraft.

Comment: Thanks it took a while but it installed itself. I had multiple 40 MB updates but it only unpacked them successfully today.